# What are the differences between primary and logical partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

What are the major differences? Which is more preferable? Are there any OS specific advantages for one over the other?

Answer (score 58):

In the legacy [MBR partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), only at most four partitions can be created (they are called "primary" partitions). To bypass this limit, one of the entries is usually made an ["extended" partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) – instead of files, it contains several "logical" partitions.

```
MBR: < primary | primary | primary | primary >

MBR: < primary | primary | extended [logical, logical, logical] >
```

In practice, the only difference is that some operating systems (namely Windows) are unable to boot from logical partitions.

A newer partition scheme, [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), is used on some recent systems, including all Intel Macs – it doesn't have such small limits, and does not need to use extended/logical partitions.

Comment: Note that you don't need to have 3 primary partitions before you can create an extended partition... or indeed any primary partitions at all.

Comment: Most brief answet on this topics I have **ever read.**

Answer (score 23):

You can have only 4 primary partitions (3 if you decide to have an extended partition), whereas you can have an arbitrary number of logical partitions. There are no OS-specific advantages other than older versions of Windows must be installed on a primary partition and that the legacy MBR bootloader can only boot from a primary partition.

Answer (score 10):

There are 3 kinds of partitions

1. Primary
2. Extended
3. Logical

And two types of partitioning scheme used now a days

- MBR   (Master Boot Record)
- GPT   (GUID Partition Table)

Primary partition, extended partition, and logical partition are much related to MBR disk, because GPT disk only contains primary partition.

On an MBR disk, there can only be 4 primary partitions or 3 primary + 1 extended partition at most.

We can install OS and save our data on any of partitions kind (primary/logical),  but the only difference is that some operating systems (namely Windows) are unable to boot from logical partitions.

An **active partition** is based on primary partition. Any one of the 4 primary partitions can be set as active partition. Since there can be 4 primary partitions with 4 different Operating Systems installed, one of the partition that is marked active is used for the *initial booting*. The active partition contains the boot loader (e.g. ntldr, bootmgr or grub/burg/lilo) to load operating systems from a disk.

**BIOS** will only recognize the active partition for loading operating system. Other partitions can’t be recognized.

The logical partition can't be set as active. 
As [here](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/active-vs-inactive-partition.html) explained.

Full Source : [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Disk_partitioning)

Answer (score 1):

they're not alternatives, it's more a point about the order you create them and their hierarchical relationship. The first is called the primary partition. Some OSs let you have more than one.  <s>Within any</s> (In addition to any) Primary you can create an extended partition, and if you want more partitions, then within the extended partition you can also create logical partitions.

thanks to grawity and ignacio for corrections.

Comment: Primary partitions always contain data, never extended partitions (primary and extended are on the same hierarchy level), their count is not OS-dependent, and the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @grawity no relationship between primary and extended then? I see.. and just read on wikipedia, a hdd can only have one extended partition. So I suppose if one wants multiple partitions, one would just create multiple primary partitions if possible, then if they need more, they'd create an extended partition to go along with the primary one(s), and if more then logical within that extended one. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (Except it only applies to MBR-partitioned disks, but other types such as GPT exist.)

Comment: @barlop: Mostly correct, except that the single extended partition restriction is due to assumptions by the OS rather than any physical or logical limit.

Comment: Having multiple extended partitions wouldn't give you anything, only waste a primary MBR entry. A single extended partition uses a linked list of EBRs, which means the amount of logical partitions is already unlimited.

Comment: @grawity does the extended contain both its own partition, and any logical partitions created?  so an extended with 3 logicals, would be 4 partitions?

Comment: @barlop: The extended partition contains "logical" partitions *instead of* a file system. It is more of a container -- it uses up a partition table entry in the MBR, but it cannot contain files directly so is not a real partition in this sense.

Comment: Actually, multiple extended partitions does have a use.  It was used by some people to separate the secondary partitions that they didn't want operating systems such as MS/PC-DOS and OS/2 to see from those that they did.  This was done by having two container partitions, one with the conventional `0x05` type and the other with a non-standard `0x85` type.  Andries Brouwer wrote about such systems years ago.

Comment: @grawity primary partitions contain only file-systems. (everything is data)

Answer (score 1):

Primary partitions have entries in [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). So, there are maximum 4 primary partitions and one of them may be extended partition. The extended partition can contain variable number of logical partitions. The extended partition contains [VBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record) by which Program control can get the information of logical partitions.