# Create a 5th partition with gparted

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I have four partitions on my hard disk drive:

1. System reserved - 100 MB -  (Windows 7 created it)
2. C: -145 GB- (My Windows 7 SP1 installed in it
3. D: -210 GB- (I use it for my software)
4. E: -210 GB- (I use it for my multimedia)

My hard disk also has 60 GB unallocated space, and I want to use this for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows.

In Ubuntu 13.04 live DVD I use gparted and try to create a new partition, but it shows an error message that say: It's not possible to create more than four partitions.

How I can solve this problem without lose my data and OS?

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/337146/what-are-the-differences-between-primary-and-logical-partition

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to do this unless you get rid of one of those partitions. This is because you just can't have more than four primary partitions.

However, if you do get rid of one them you could create and extended partition in its space, and in that even more logical partitions.

Comment: That is not strictly speaking true.  The new GPT partitioning format will allow pretty much unlimited partitions.  That said, using GPT is not trivial and requires BIOS support.  Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx

Comment: I know, but if his computer is complaining, then he currently is not using GPT.  Also, as you say, changing it to that may be a small nightmare, the fact he does not want data loss would also not help unless he has some HDDs.