# Can not create logical partition on an external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a strange problem. I have an external HDD which I use for a Linux distro I use.

I've deleted all the partitions on it in order to create some new partitions and now I have one huge 950GB unallocated partition. My problem is that I cannot create an extended or logical partition. I have used 4 different software to re-partition my drive, but I can only have 4 primary partitions. I am sure that I had 2 logical partitions before all of this on this external HDD.

I have used:

1. Live Ubuntu
2. Live Gparted
3. MiniTool partition
4. EaseUS Partition Master

In all above methods I can not choose extended or logical partition because they are inactive. I know 4 primary partitions are enough for me, but I would like to know what is wrong that I can not create an extended or logical partition.

Comment: this could be a HDD-firmware-specific issue, that's the only thing I can imagine. or something got corrupted. I would say: try making 4 (Each 32 mb?) primary partitions and then try to create an additional partition from inside the windows disk management. then delete the primary partitions. Good luck. Also note that when you choose to have a GUID Partition Table then you can have 128 primary partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You may only 4 primary partitions. Or use software. The boot loader Bootstar can make 15 primary partitions and emulate HDD partitions with the type marker.

If you need an extended partition and replace it with one primary partition, then the number of partitions is 3 primary and 1 extended partition. Extended partition, in turn, may contain a sufficiently large number of logical partitions.

Answer (score 0):

The [master boot record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) A.K.A MBR contains only 4 entries for describing partitions. As a result an MBR disk can only have 4 primary partitions, or 3 primary + 1 extended ones. The [extended partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition) is used to contain other logical ones. So **all the logical partitions must be placed right next to each other**. You cannot create a logical partition that is spaced from the extended volume

See also [What are the differences between primary and logical partition?](https://superuser.com/q/337146/241386)

Answer (score 0):

[Click here](https://superuser.com/a/972305/496719) and checkout that answer (Start at step 4), It shows you how to create Logical partition, It doesn't state its creating a logical one but believe me it is.

#### It is very well documented, Check it out, the software used is the best one out but very complex looking to noobs xD Just follow the tutorial and easy :)